# unpackaging play framework from an rpm - dependency error on org.slf4j.api

Tags: deployment, playframework-2.0, slf4j, rpm

Hi I packaged my play framework application in a rpm and I get this error while unpackaging it

```
Examining target/rpm/RPMS/noarch/my-app.noarch.rpm: my-app.noarch
Marking target/rpm/RPMS/noarch/my-app.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package my-app.noarch 0:1-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: osgi(org.slf4j.api) for package: my-app.noarch
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirrors.arsc.edu
 * updates: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
**Error: Package: my-app.noarch (/my-app.noarch)
           Requires: osgi(org.slf4j.api)**
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I believe this is dependency within play framework. Any idea on how to get rid of this?

Thanks,

Jennifer